# How can I make an indented list and use double arrow as my character

Tags: css

I have a list that I want to look like this:

```
» Hello here is a line that
  breaks
» Hello here is a line that
  breaks
» Hello here is a line that
  breaks
```

I use :before to add the double arrows:

```
li{
  width: 80px;
}
li:before {
  content: "\0273";
}
```

This results in a list that lookd like this:

```
» Hello here is a line that
breaks
» Hello here is a line that
breaks
» Hello here is a line that
breaks
```

How can I indent the second line aswell? I don't want to use images.

Comment: Please, post your jsfiddle.

Comment: What does your html look like?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  padding-left: 16px;
  text-indent: -14px;
    width: 100px;
}

li:before {
  content: "+";
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g5vzhbwy/1/)